# A battery with zero internal resistance connected to identical resistors in parallel

Tags: parallel, ohms-law

How is it possible that the current in each branch of a set of identical resistors in parallel would change when adding one more parallel resistor?

I know that since the battery doesn't have internal resistance (by assumption), its voltage would equal the voltage drop across the parallel combination, that is V<sub>bat</sub> = V<sub>ab</sub> = V<sub>R1</sub> = V<sub>R2</sub> = … = V<sub>Rn</sub>.

V<sub>bat</sub> is constant, therefore V<sub>Rn</sub> is constant, and since V<sub>Rn</sub> = I<sub>Rn</sub>·Rn, then I<sub>Rn</sub> should be constant.

So, if we say we have a parallel combination of n identical resistors, then I<sub>Rn</sub> = I/n = constant.

However, adding resistor n+1 makes the new I<sub>Rn</sub> = I/(n+1), but this would alter V<sub>Rn</sub> since we know that Rn is constant, so that would then contradict the fact that V<sub>Rn</sub> should equal the constant V<sub>bat</sub>!

How this is possible?

Comment: By assumption, the internal resistance is zero, you are right. And also all wires/connections are ideal (zero Ohms)...

Comment: The current PER POWERED BRANCH or PER POWERED RESISTOR will not change if resistors are added or subtracted. The total current will be proportional to the number of resistors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you assumed that \$I\$ stays the same. If you add another parallel resistor, then \$I\$ goes up.

Answer (score 2):

You assume the total resistance of the circuit remains the same but this is not the case.Counter example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs93yJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

the total resistance seen from the voltage source of the first circuit (from left to right) is 50Ω while the resistance seen from the voltage source of the second circuit (from left to right) IS 33.3Ω

Answer (score 1):

Voltage is constant, the supply is ideal and wiring too. Therefore, each individual resistor has the same constant voltage over it, so the other resistors don't affect the voltage over each resistor and current through each resistor.

But the ideal wiring and ideal battery needs to output and deliver the total current to all the resistors. The more resistors you add, the more current flows in the wiring.

Answer (score 1):

If the voltage source and connections are ideal, adding resistors in parallel will only affect the added resistor. Reality, of course, is different.

Similarly, adding resistors in series with an ideal current source would not affect the current, no matter how many you add.